# React native: Vertically centre View inside a view

Tags: css, react-native, flexbox

I have a View inside a view. And I'm trying to vertically center the child view.
Below is the sample code:

```
              <View style={globalStyle.text}>
                <Text style={[globalStyle.name]}>
                  {name}
                </Text>
                <View style={globalStyle.timeContainer}>
                 <Image style={globalStyle.tinyIcon} source={require('./Thumbnails/time-tiny.png')}/>
                <Text style={globalStyle.audio_count}>
                  {this.state.audioTime[rowID]}
                </Text>
                </View>
              </View>
```

When there is text alone `justifyContent: 'center'` works fine to vertically center the child content. However when there is a child `View` involved it doesn't work. How can I achieve this?

Here is a picture of the same: I'm trying to make the text inside the white box vertically center aligned.
[image]

Comment: You need to be more clear with what you mean. A drawing can be helpful and the CSS is a must.

Comment: @LGSon Have updated the question. Basically, the problem is to vertically centre all the content of a View.

Comment: Generally, for flex items in a row direction you use `alignItems: 'center'`